# How to use mapGetters with Vuex Modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

i have added modules in `store/index.js`

```
import NavMessage from './nav/message/index';
new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    NavMessage,
  },
});
```

my message/index.js

```
import state from './state';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
};
```

here is getters

```
const getters = () => ({
  getCount: state => {
    return state.count;
  },
});

export default getters;
```

i am trying to get data from `NavMessage/getCount`

```
...mapGetters({
    count: 'NavMessage/getCount',
  }),
```

but i am getting error `unknown getter: NavMessage/getCount`

help me thank

Comment: Do you want to use namespacing? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing You'll need to add `namespaced: true` to the module if you do. I also suggest checking the case of `getCount` as the first letter seems to be in upper-case in the error message.

Comment: @skirtle thanks for the reply but still getting same error

Comment: I still need to know whether you want to use namespacing. The correct fix depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a working example.

I've made two important changes:

1. I've added `namespaced: true` to the module.
2. I've removed the wrapper function from around the `getters`.

If you don't want to use namespacing then you'll need to change the `mapGetters` argument to `count: 'getCount'` instead. The `NavMessage/` prefix is only required with namespacing.

```js
const mapGetters = Vuex.mapGetters

const state = {
  count: 6
}

const getters = {
  getCount: state => {
    return state.count
  }
}

const mutations = {}

const NavMessage = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    NavMessage
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  store,

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      count: 'NavMessage/getCount',
    })
  }
})

console.log(app.count)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
```

You've tagged the question with Nuxt. If you are using Nuxt I strongly suggest reading their guide to using the store:

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store

Nuxt does things a little differently but as far as I'm aware you still shouldn't have a function wrapper around your `getters`. The `namespaced: true` will be added automatically and you shouldn't need to create the `new Vuex.Store` yourself. Nuxt creates the store itself and adds modules based on the folder structure.

Comment: thank you for your reply i did with your login in my app now i am getting getters check screenshot https://prnt.sc/q98ftq but still getting same error